# Perl MySQL - How do I split a search string and match with LIKE %$word1%$word2% "dynamically"?

Tags: mysql, perl, split, sql-like

I am stuck again.

I have a search string and assigned it to a variable:

```
my $search =  'foo bar blue widget'
$search =~ s/[\n\r]+|^\s+|\s+$//g; #remove leading and trailing spaces n stuff
```

I was using

```
SELECT FROM `sometable` WHERE `coltosearch` LIKE '%$search%'
```

But, would match only "foo bar blue widget" OR "foo".

I want to match "foo bars" or "foobar" too.

So, I think I would have to do:

```
 my $search =  'foo bar blue widget';
    $search =~ s/[\n\r]+|^\s+|\s+$//g; #remove leading and trailing spaces n stuff
 my $search1 =  $search;
    $search1 =~ s/^\s+|\s+$|\s*//g; #remove all spaces

   SELECT FROM `sometable` WHERE `coltosearch` LIKE '%$search%' OR LIKE '%$search1%'
```

Well, that may be fine for "foo bar blue widget" and "foobarbluewidget". (if it worked)

So, I am guessing I will have to loop through $search, and assign variables to each word.

But, I never know how many words I will have in $search.

So, I am stuck. Could I do something like:

```
my $search =  'foo bar blue widget'; #in from search form. Actually a $var
$search1 =~ s/^\s+|\s+$|\s*//g; #remove all spaces
$search1 = "%$search1%"; # Makes %foobarbluewidget%

## Now make individual words somehow ##
my @searcharry;
my $cnt='0';
my $searchword;
my @searchsplit = $search;
while $searchword (@searchsplit){
push (@searcharry,$searchword[$cnt]);
$cnt++;
}
```

But how do I get @searcharry into:

```
$search =~ s/\s/%/gi;
$search =~ s/%%/%/gi; #I think makes %foo%bar%blue%widget%
```

So I can:

```
 SELECT FROM `sometable` WHERE `coltosearch` LIKE '$search' OR LIKE '$search1'
```

I am probably way off base. This is really difficult for me.
I just want to match any words in the search string or match if all words are run together.

Sorry for being such a noob. My crude attempt, I believe is an insult to Perl and real coders.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: MySQL's RLIKE might be easier to work with: SELECT * FROM `tab` WHERE `col` RLIKE 'foo|bar|blue|widget';

Comment: If the string contains all search terms run together, then it would also match any of the search terms. Why is this any more complicated than `col LIKE '%$term1%' OR col LIKE '%$term2%' OR ... col LIKE '%$term4%'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `$string = "foo bar blue widget"`, then you'd do something like:

```
my @values = split '\s+', $string;
my $where = "WHERE $col LIKE ?";
$where .= " OR LIKE ?" x $#values;
```

This will create a where clause of `WHERE column LIKE ? OR LIKE ? OR LIKE ? OR LIKE ?` for your `"foo bar blue widget"` string.

Then you use [DBI placeholders and bind values](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) so you don't have to worry about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) on your code.

Comment: @CanSpice Thank you I think I am understanding but, is that in a loop or something? Can I have a more verbose example? Thanks so much..

Comment: @Stephayne: No, it's not in a loop, it's just straight code. You would build up your SQL statement (`SELECT * FROM whatever`) and then concatenate the where clause from the above code snippet. Then you'd prepare and execute the statement as described in the first link in my response.

Comment: @CanSpice So where does the $col get set to column? Also, what is the "x $#values". I really do apologize for my lack of understanding. I did try to find what they were before commenting again. P.S. I am using placeholders and DBI but, tried to keep the question code shorter. So, the execute($var1,$var2,(thru how many $where)) would need to be dynamically generated too.

Comment: @Stephayne `$col` is whatever your column name is. It's a variable. The `x $#values` means "repeat the string before the `x` $#values times", and `$#values` is the number of elements in the `@values` array, minus one. You wouldn't have to do `execute($var1, $var2, ...)` because you already have all of those variables in the `@values` array.

Comment: @CanSpice Now I am REALLY CONFUSED. Do you mean like:  "$dsn = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT @values});" So How would I execute the query?? "$dsn->execute(what?);" ?? I apologize again. I must understand this.

Comment: Stephayne's code would be used by writing something like `$sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT FROM sometable $where}); if ($sth) { $result = $sth->execute( @values ) }` ... simultaneously prepping a WHERE clause with `?`s and creating an array to be used with it is a common motif.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I will mark as answered even though I don't fully understand but, I am sure you answer is accurate. Thank you for explaining that as well @Jamie